# How to update OpenSSL on windows 7?

Tags: windows, openssl, cygwin

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and In my cgywin prompt I can run

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
```

and see the current version. I want to update this to the latest version but can't find an official source on how to do this. What's the easiest way to do this? I hope theirs a command line I can use in the same window.

Thanks.

Comment: Your official source is under [Update Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) from the [Cygwin homepage](http://cygwin.com).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To upgrade Cygwin's openssl you just need to run the installer and select the newer version. Cygwin's site states the following:

> The setup.exe utility tracks the versions of all installed components and provides the mechanism for installing or updating everything available from this site for Cygwin.

The steps to upgrade are the following:

1. Go to [Cygwin's Site](http://cygwin.com/install.html) and download [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe).
2. **Run setup.exe** and click next until you hit the "Select Packages" page.
3. Type the package you want to upgrade (openssl) in the search box.
4. Select the version you want to install.
5. Click Next and wait for it to install/download it.

[image: Cygwin OpenSSL Installation]

After the installation/upgrade is complete you should be able to see the new version in Cygwin with the following command:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012

$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

You also may be able to build Openssl from source but I have never tried. I figure Cygwin handles the installation/upgrade for a reason.

Also, OpenSSL can be installed without Cygwin with one of the binaries at the following location: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html